What kind of mistake/error that arbitrator can make (either intentionally/unintentionally) such that the court still won't overturn it?
I was reading about the OXFORD HEALTH PLANS LLC v. SUTTER case and i was baffled that arbitrators are allowed to make mistake/error and the court still won't overturn it, even if it was a grave error.

. . .  All we say is that convincing a
court of an arbitrator’s error—even his grave error—is not
enough. So long as the arbitrator was “arguably construing” the contract—which this one was—a court may not
correct his mistakes under §10(a)(4). [ . . . ]  The potential for those mistakes is the price of agreeing
to arbitration.


. . .  But §10(a)(4) bars that course: It permits courts to vacate an
arbitral decision only when the arbitrator strayed from his delegated
task of interpreting a contract, not when he performed that task
poorly.


. . .  A party seeking relief under §10(a)(4) bears a heavy burden. “It
is not enough . . . to show that the [arbitrator] committed an error—
or even a serious error.” Stolt-Nielsen, 559 U. S., at 671. Because the
parties “bargained for the arbitrator’s construction of their agreement,” an arbitral decision “even arguably construing or applying the
contract” must stand, regardless of a court’s view of its (de)merits.

This shows that there exist "mistakes" or "error" that arbitrator can make such that the court won't overturn it. This open the following question: What kind of mistake that an arbitrator can make such that the court still won't overturn it?
As in the quote above, the court view the potential for those mistakes as the price of agreeing to arbitration. But what if the arbitration was forced instead of voluntary? for example, smartphone software publisher are forced to agree to app's store arbitration agreement due to their monopoly in the market. If the arbitration was forced instead of voluntary, does arbitrator still allowed to make mistake ?

AIUI in the US the law does not recognise a contract of adhesion as "forced" because the other party can in theory just say "no" and walk away. Obviously this ignores the monopoly power of an app store, but that's a whole separate body of law. In the UK we have the unfair contracts act, which at least prevents this happening to consumers.

It seems arbitration in the USA has the purpose of giving large companies much power to avoid having to treat customers fairly. In Germany, the typical case works like this: Company puts up a sign that they will submit to arbitration. As the customer you can choose arbitration. You can reject the result; the company can do the same ONCE and remove their sign about arbitration. If the arbitration fails, you can go to court (or you may read why the arbitration was against you and decide that a court is a waste of money). Very cheap and useful if the customer is not sure about their rights.

@gnasher729 That's called court-ordered arbitration in the US. In my state, any lawsuit under $25k has to go through such arbitration, as dictated by court rules. Small claims court (typically <~$5000) is also a form of arbitration with even stricter requirements (often no lawyers, no appeals).

@user71659 Often no lawyers, but usually some form of appeal.


What kind of mistake/error that arbitrator can make (either
intentionally/unintentionally) such that the court still won't
overturn it?

Errors of law. Errors of fact. Pretty much no matter how glaring. The quoted court opinion accurately reflects U.S. law on this issue.
The main grounds for overturning an arbitration award if there is no doubt that the parties were bound by an arbitration agreement are bribery (and similar kinds of corruption) and not allowing the parties to introduce relevant evidence in their favor.
Sometimes an arbitration award can be overruled for exceeding the scope of arbitration authorized by the arbitration agreement, but that is interpreted generously in favor of allowing matters to be arbitrated.
Notably, few countries other than the U.S. give such absolute deference to an arbitrator's decision or allow arbitration at all in the breadth of circumstances where it can be compelled in U.S. law.

But what if the arbitration was forced instead of voluntary? for
example, smartphone software publisher are forced to agree to app's
store arbitration agreement due to their monopoly in the market. If
the arbitration was forced instead of voluntary, does arbitrator still
allowed to make mistake?

Doesn't matter. Doesn't matter if you didn't sign an arbitration agreement or a contract containing one. If there was contract formation of the arbitration clause part of the contract (even if the contract as a whole is invalid) then the standard of review of an arbitrator's decision is the same.
Often, even questions like duress are resolved by the arbitrator and not the court, although this is a highly technical area of the law with a lot of not entirely consistent court rulings.

None
The parties agreed to arbitrate and abide by the arbitrator’s decision. If the arbitrator is shit, that’s what they agreed to.
Grounds for setting aside an arbitral decision are extremely circumspect and, in general, mistakes by the arbitrator are not included, only actual corruption or bias (which are not mistakes) or jurisdictional error (in which case the arbitrator is not actually an arbitrator).

Does this mean you can appeal against a lower court but not against an arbitrator?

This is completely wrong. Read 9 USC 10 and 11.

@curious_cat yes, one of the advantages of arbitration is that it is final and binding.

@user71659 The post, as edited now, seems to accurately state the law.
